# How to combine loops to assign a valule to a text box

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform

I have this code for a userform and I am trying to reduce it to just one loop (since I did not figure out how to do it, I just made one loop for each year).

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU3mH.jpg)

It takes data from the user and stores the odd textbox values in the first 6 rows of excel sheet. Followed by the even textbox numbers in the next 6 rows of a excel sheet(for 12 total months).The textboxes on top of each year are odd numbered(1,3,5,7,9,11, for the boxes in 89; 13,15,17,19,21,23 for the boxes in 90, etc). My code does that untill it hits 95, but the code is too big and could be reduced to one loop. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Inserir_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Planilha1")

'89

x = 1
y = 7
i = 0
j = 5

Do While x < 7

ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & x + i).Value

x = x + 1
i = i + 1

Loop

Do While y < 13

ws.Cells(y, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & y - j).Value

y = y + 1
j = j - 1

Loop

'90

Z = 13
w = 19
k = 0
m = 5

Do While Z < 19

ws.Cells(Z, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & Z + k).Value

Z = Z + 1
k = k + 1

Loop

Do While w < 25

ws.Cells(w, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & w - m).Value

w = w + 1
m = m - 1

Loop

'91

a = 25
b = 31
n = 0
o = 5

Do While a < 31

ws.Cells(a, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & a + n).Value

a = a + 1
n = n + 1

Loop

Do While b < 37

ws.Cells(b, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & b - o).Value

b = b + 1
o = o - 1

Loop

'92

e = 37
f = 43
g = 0
h = 5

Do While e < 43

ws.Cells(e, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & e + g).Value

e = e + 1
g = g + 1

Loop

Do While f < 49

ws.Cells(f, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & f - h).Value

f = f + 1
h = h - 1

Loop

'93

aa = 49
bb = 55
cc = 0
dd = 5

Do While aa < 55

ws.Cells(aa, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & aa + cc).Value

aa = aa + 1
cc = cc + 1

Loop

Do While bb < 61

ws.Cells(bb, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & bb - dd).Value

bb = bb + 1
dd = dd - 1

Loop

'94

xx = 61
yy = 67
zz = 0
ww = 5

Do While xx < 67

ws.Cells(xx, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & xx + zz).Value

xx = xx + 1
zz = zz + 1

Loop

Do While yy < 73

ws.Cells(yy, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & yy - ww).Value

yy = yy + 1
ww = ww - 1

Loop

'95

ax = 73
ay = 79
az = 0
aw = 5

Do While ax < 79

ws.Cells(ax, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & ax + az).Value

ax = ax + 1
az = az + 1

Loop

Do While ay < 85

ws.Cells(ay, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & ay - aw).Value

ay = ay + 1
aw = aw - 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: you could either put the values that change onto a worksheet and use `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` to retrieve the correct values, or else you could choose the correct value in VBA using a `Select..Case` statement.  But that's an awful lot of stuff to expect people to look through, you might want to check out [mcve] (especially the "Minimal" part). Perhaps you could post only 2 sets and figure out the pattern to add the others yourself.

Comment: Also, this question is not about userforms. It is about loops. I've updated you title to be more representative of your problem.

Comment: @ashleedawg *I've updated you title* Could've been updated indentations also :)

Comment: It would **really** help this question if you included a shot of the form that showed how the textboxes are laid out *and* what they're named - that way we could help you figure out what the pattern is here (I'm sure there's one)... otherwise it just looks like pretty much random counters, not sure anyone will want to spend more than 15 minutes of their free time decyphering what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're after but I think you should try something like this dim an array with your textboxes and then do a for each, something like this:

```
Dim Arr_TextStat = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, Textbox6}
For each TextBoxM in Arr_TextStat
Select Case TextBoxM.Text 

Case >20 
ws.Cells(y, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & y - j).Value

y = y + 1
j = j - 1

Case > 14 
ws.Cells(ay, 1).Value = Me.Controls("Textbox" & ay - aw).Value

ay = ay + 1
aw = aw - 1

End select
Next
```

The idea is to loop through the value of each textbox and return an action with your defined cases.

This is how I loop through textboxes filling them or creating events based on their values.

Hope it helps